# Issues with unordered_map

Tags: c++, class, graph, dictionary

I'm trying to implement various data structures and algorithms for learning purposes.

At the moment I'm trying to implement a Graph class template but I'm having issues with trying to use STL `unordered_map` (and `consequently priority_queue` in the future).

Basically what happens at the moment is, for some reason, the template types don't match up when trying to initialize the vertex map within the graph. From what I understand, since I only plan to use key types from the native C++ types, as long as my value type is a pointer I shouldn't need to do any extra work apart from a copy constructor for my custom vertex class. The default comparer/hasher should suffice. But it doesn't and the error I'm receiving is kind of incomprehensible.

The error:

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::unordered_map<T,graph<T>::vertex *,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

The code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
class vertex;
template <class T>
class graph {
public:

graph() { verts = unordered_map<T, vertex*>(); }
~graph() {
    for each(auto v in verts)
        delete(v);
    delete(verts); 
}
private:
unordered_map<T, vertex*> verts;

// --- Inner Classes ---

struct path {
    vertex *dest;
    double cost;

    path(vertex *d = nullptr, double c = 0.0) : dest(d) : cost(c) {}

    inline int compare(const path& p) {
        auto other = p.cost;

        return cost < other ? -1 :
            cost > other ? 1 : 0;
    }
};

struct edge {
    vertex *dest;
    double cost;

    edge(vertex *d = nullptr, double c = 0.0) : dest(d) : cost(c) {}
};

class vertex {
public:
    // Vertex relationships
    T name;
    vector<edge>* adj;

    // Path Finding Information
    double distance;
    vertex *prev;
    int scratch;

    void reset_path_finding() {
        distance = double.infinity();
        prev = nullptr;
        scratch = 0;
    }

    vertex(T name = default(T)) : name(name) : adj(new vector<edge>) : 
        distance(double.infinity()) : prev(nullptr) : scratch(0) {}
    vertex(const vertex& v) {
        name = v.name;
        adj = v.adj;
        distance = v.distance;
        prev = v.prev;
        scratch = v.scratch;
    }
    ~vertex() { delete(adj); }
private:
};
};

int main()
{
graph<int> myGraph = graph<int>();

cout << "Press any key to continue..." << endl;
int x;
cin >> x;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please point the line in the source the error is about?

Comment: By the way, when you declare a variable (class member, local or global) like the local `myGraph` in the `main` function or `verts` in the `graph` class, you don't have to initialize the way you do. Just declaring it will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you use the nested class `graph::vertex` before declaring it. Further confusion is caused because you've declared `class vertex` *outside* `graph`, so the compiler initially thinks you mean that class. You could declare `vertex` near the start of `graph`:

```
template <class T>
class graph {
    class vertex;
private:
    // and so on
};
```

There are several other syntax errors, which should be obvious if you look at the lines referred to by the error messages. The syntax for a range-based for loop is

```
for (auto v : verts)  // not for each(auto v in verts)
```

This gives you key-value pairs, so to delete the `vertex`, you need

```
delete v.second;
```

Better still, change `verts` into `unordered_map<T, vertex>`, containing objects rather than pointers, and it will manage all its memory automatically - you won't need a destructor at all.

The syntax for a value-initialised temporary is

```
T()  // not default(T)
```

Clauses in a constructor's initialiser list are separated by commas, not colons:

```
path(vertex *d = nullptr, double c = 0.0) : dest(d) , cost(c) {}
                                                    ^ not :
```

A `double` with infinite value is

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() // not double.infinity()
```

for which you need to in include `<limits>`.

`verts` doesn't need deleting in the destructor, since you don't `new` it. Nor does it need assigning from a default-constructed temporary in the constructor, since it's just been default-constructed.

There are a few  places where you are making life difficult for yourself through unnecessary use of pointers and `new`. Try to avoid `new` except when you really need it; and learn about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), especially the use of smart pointers and containers, for when you do.

Comment: Wow, Thanks. I'm going to scrap this code and do it again tomorrow with this feedback. I've had enough poking around trying to get it to work. 

But a lot of those things you point out weren't even coming up as error messages when I try compile that class as a whole. (MS C++) Unless I force it into main as a little test snippet and sometimes not even then.  For example that incorrect for each syntax compiles and behaves as expected. 

I am downloading clang on this new computer, but since I live in a rural area the download is taking a little while.

Comment: @MorphingDragon: Since it's a template, a lot of the errors won't be detected unless the function or class they're in is instantiated - which won't (usually) happen unless the program uses it. Try building up large classes by adding a small bit of functionality at a time, writing tests as you go, so you don't end up with a huge pile of errors to trawl through.